# Python3/Django - QuerySet not updating

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm creating a website that allows for the creation of events, and those events will be shown on both the home page, and on the events list, so that people can click on the events on view the descriptions of them, as well as check in at the event. I'm having an issue getting a query set within a class to update when a new event is added.

So this function is for our main home page. The query_set updates every time you go back to the page, so when a new event is added, it is shown on this page.

```
def index(request):
    num_future_events = Event.objects.filter(date__gte=today).filter(approved=True).count()
    query_set = Event.objects.filter(date__gte=today).filter(approved=True).order_by('date', 'time')[:3]

    context = {
        'num_future_events': num_future_events,
        'query_set': query_set
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

This is a class for the events list page on my site. It uses a query set but since the class is only ever called once, the query set will only update with the class's initialization.

```
class EventListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Event
    query_set = Event.objects.filter(date__gte=today).exclude(approved=False).order_by('date', 'time')[:21]
    template_name = 'listPage.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.query_set
```

I was hoping to get some help with making it so when a new event is added, the query set in the EventListView class updates automatically so that it will be displayed on this page.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Django each time appends `.all()` to it in the `QuerySet` to force re-evaluation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we take a look at [Django's source code for a `ListView`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.list/ListView/#get_queryset), we see:

> ```
> def get_queryset(self):
>     """
>     Return the list of items for this view.
>     The return value must be an iterable and may be an instance of
>     `QuerySet` in which case `QuerySet` specific behavior will be enabled.
>     """
>     if self.queryset is not None:
>         queryset = self.queryset
>         if isinstance(queryset, QuerySet):
>             queryset = queryset.all()
>     elif self.model is not None:
>         queryset = self.model._default_manager.all()
>     else:
>         raise ImproperlyConfigured(
>             "%(cls)s is missing a QuerySet. Define "
>             "%(cls)s.model, %(cls)s.queryset, or override "
>             "%(cls)s.get_queryset()." % {
>                 'cls': self.__class__.__name__
>             }
>         )
>     ordering = self.get_ordering()
>     if ordering:
>         if isinstance(ordering, str):
>             ordering = (ordering,)
>         queryset = queryset.order_by(*ordering)
>     return queryset
> ```

Django thus each time construct a *new* queryset, by calling `.all()`  it makes a *unevaluated* clone of the queryset, such that this is forced to get reevaluated.

In this case, I thus propose that you do *not* overwrite `get_queryset`, but simply use the `queryset` attribute, like:

```
class EventListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Event
    queryset = Event.objects.filter(
        date__gte=today
    ).exclude(
        approved=False
    ).order_by('date', 'time')[:21]
    template_name = 'listPage.html'
```

Or if you really want to override the `get_queryset` function you can use:

```
class EventListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'listPage.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Event.objects.filter(
            date__gte=today
        ).exclude(approved=False).order_by('date', 'time')[:21]
```

or:

```
class EventListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'listPage.html'
    query_set = Event.objects.filter(
        date__gte=today
    ).exclude(approved=False).order_by('date', 'time')[:21]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.query_set.all()
```